# Having clause in GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class named Keyword and I need to run a query to get all the duplicate keywords in the system, base on some criteria.
The query in MySQL is somethine like this:

```
select keywordid, md5, match_type, count(md5)
from keyword
where site_id = 'MLU'
and customer_id = 1075613440
group by md5
having count(md5) > 1;
```

Now I  need to "translate" this query to Grails but the requirement from my boss is to aviod HQL.
Is it possible to do it?

For now all I have is this:

```
def dupKws = criteria.list {
    eq('siteId', siteId)
    eq('customerId', account.customerId)
    projections {
        groupProperty('md5')
        groupProperty('matchType')
        rowCount()
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run this query in grails with:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql    
def query = """ select keywordid, md5, match_type, count(md5)\
                    from keyword\
                    where site_id = 'MLU'\
                    and customer_id = 1075613440\
                    group by md5\
                    having count(md5) > 1 """
    Sql sql = new Sql(datasource)
    sql.execute(query)
```

Comment: Hi David. Yes, actually I wanted to avoid using HQL and wanted to find a way to do it with Criteria, if possible. It seems it can't be done, or at least I haven't found the way. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Robert, I have edited the answer to use plain sql. 
You can see a tutorial about how to use it here http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Tutorial+6+-+Groovy+SQL